# How to parse a JSON array of strings?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to parse an array of strings (identifiers) using Jackson. I didn't find any example of it on the internet, all of them show how to deserialize arrays of objects of some class, but I need just to parse an array of strings (without writing a model class for it), how can I do that? Example of JSON:

```json
[
"UUID",
"UUID",
...
]
```

Comment: See https://www.twilio.com/blog/java-json-with-jackson, "tree model examples".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`ObjectMapper.readValue()`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue-java.lang.String-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference-) method with a [`TypeReference`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to get a list of strings:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "[\"UUID\",\"UUID\"]";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<String> values = mapper.readValue(json,
                new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
    }
}
```

Or you can use the [`ObjectMapper.readValue()`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) method with the `String[].class` to get an array of strings:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "[\"UUID\",\"UUID\"]";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String[] values = mapper.readValue(json, String[].class);
    }
}
```